# Install pygame in a virtualenv

Tags: pygame, virtualenv, fedora

I use fedora 20, Python 2.7 and virtualenv 1.10.1. I want to install pygame in virtualenv and I get

> You are installing a potentially insecure and unverifiable file. Future versions of pip will default to disallowing insecure files.
>     HTTP error 400 while getting http://www.pygame.org/../../ftp/pygame-1.6.2.tar.bz2 (from http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml)
>     Could not install requirement pygame because of error HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

I found [this](http://github.com/xamox/pygame) in GitHub, so I tried without success

> ```
> pip install git+http://github.com/xamox/pygame
> ```

Asking for missing dependencies. I know that I have to install sdl*. Can I do it in virtualenv or do I have to do it on the system? Any recommendation?

I installed PySDL but still nothing

Answer (score 6):

Finally what I did to install pygame on virtualenv is:

```
su -c "yum-builddep pygame"
```

due to pygame installer is waiting for user confirmation about missing dependencies I need to pipe a "yes". So

```
yes y | pip install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
```

or

```
yes y |pip install git+http://github.com/xamox/pygame
```

The smpeg-config dependency is only available on fedora16 so I ignored and that's worked.

Comment: Hey, instead of adding [solved] at the top of the question like traditional forums, we prefer that you just use the accept mark under the correct answer's score (even if it's yours!). After you do, feel free to flag this comment as obsolete so that it may be removed from your answer.

Comment: The command was stalling without any prompt. For me, all that was needed is passing the "yes" option. Thanks for the solution. This worked on Ubuntu 14.1.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Ubuntu, and fixed it with:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-pygame
```

Interesting, I've seen this solution in some resources, but it didn't work for me, because `build-dep` looked not like an option, but like some package to install, so I tried to run `apt-get install build-dep`. Of course, with no success. @b10n1k 's answer helped me to figure out my mistake. :)

Comment: How is your solution installing to virtualenv? Sure it works but that is not what the question was about. The solution here is the "yes" option because the command: "pip install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame", will just stop without a prompt.

Comment: @anber sometimes it's impossible to install some libraty to virtualenv if there are no binaries required by this library, installed globally. So you have to install them.